# How can I create a multiboot USB drive? i.e. one USB stick that can be booted to Windows, Linux, diagnostic tools, etc

Tags: multi-boot, bootable-media, rufus

I'm aware this can't be done with Rufus, and I've tried YUMI to no avail.

I use several diagnostic tools on a regular basis (Hiren's Windows Boot CD, Lenovo utilities and a lightweight Linux OS) and would like to consolidate them to one USB drive I carry on my keychain.

My understanding is that all I need to do is make several partitions, format them properly and image each with whatever image I'd like. When I reach the boot menu, I'll see all X partitions listed and will be able to pick and choose which image I'd like to run.

However, this hasn't worked for me in practice. Has anybody been able to do this? Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: I did not understand why not Yumi. For me it is the greatest one for do that...

Comment: You have Yumi and Yumi UEFI, which one did you try?

Comment: I tried Yumi UEFI and attempted to install Ubuntu and sysLinux on it. What's different about Yumi (not UEFI)?

Answer (score 2):

Besides YUMI, there are four other apps you might try:

- SARDU MultiBoot USB and DVD Creator
- MultiBootUSB
- MultiSystem
- WinSetupFromUSB

Some works on Windows, some works on both Windows and Linux.

Source: https://www.linuxbabe.com/apps/create-multiboot-usb-linux-windows-iso

Comment: I'm trying MultiBootUSB and have managed to get one of my Linux distros to work. At the very least it lets me get pas the boot menu, to the distro selection menu. Thanks for the suggestions! I'll try the others when I get a chance tomorrow.

Comment: Glad that it can help you to get things done.